# Getting error in Unity Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, uwp, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 3D game on unity for UWP. I'm getting the following error while creating app package. Please help me how can I remove the error from my project.

[image]

> The command ""E:\Game Project\Win
>   Build\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -platform=uap -lock="E:\Game
>   Project\Win Build\Sub_Challenge\project.lock.json" -bits=32
>   -configuration=Debug -removeDebuggableAttribute=False -path="." -path="..\Players\UAP\x86\Debug" "E:\Game Project\Win Build\Sub_Challenge\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" "E:\Game
>   Project\Win Build\Sub_Challenge\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "E:\Game
>   Project\Win Build\Sub_Challenge\Assembly-UnityScript.dll" "E:\Game
>   Project\Win Build\Sub_Challenge\UnityEngine.dll" "E:\Game Project\Win
>   Build\Sub_Challenge\UnityEngine.Networking.dll" "E:\Game Project\Win
>   Build\Sub_Challenge\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "E:\Game Project\Win
>   Build\Sub_Challenge\HOTween.dll"" exited with code
>   1.    Sub_Challenge   E:\Game Project\Win Build\Sub_Challenge\Sub_Challenge.csproj    297

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`HOTween` doesn't support WinRT/UWP API.

In our project we changed from `HOTWeen` to `DOTween` library and all works good.

Comment: After removing HOTween from my project I got following error:

Comment: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Sub_Challenge

Comment: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll' Sub_Challenge E:\Game Project\Win Build New Without HOTween\Sub_Challenge\Sub_Challenge.csproj